# Converting int to decimal in procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, types

Hey guys I wrote a procedure to convert an integer to decimal, but whenever I execute the procedure I get this error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Procedure gradesInsert, Line 9
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.
>
> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Procedure gradesInsert, Line 10
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

This is the table that I created.

```
CREATE TABLE French 
(
        StudentId int Primary key,
        StudentName varchar(75),
        Class varchar (15),
        SubjectName varchar(25) DEFAULT ('Mathematics'),
        FirstPeriod int,
        SecondPeriod int,
        ThirdPeriod int,
        FirstSemesterExam int,
        FirstSemesterAvg decimal(2,2),
        FourthPeriod int,
        FifthPeriod int,
        SixPeriod int,
        SecondSemesterExam int,
        SecondSemesterAvg decimal(2,2)
)
```

This is the procedure and how it is called.

```
create proc gradesInsert
    @StuId int, @p1 int, @p2 int, @p3 int, @firstExam int, 
    @p4 int, @p5 int,   @p6 int, @SecondExam int
As
    declare @add1 int = @p1 + @p2 + @p3 + @firstExam
    declare @add2 int = @p4 + @p2 + @p6 + @SecondExam

    declare @firstAvg decimal(2,2) = cast(@add1 / 4.0 as decimal(2,2))
    declare @SecondAvg decimal(2,2) = cast(@add2 / 4.0 as decimal(2,2))
begin
    update dbo.French
    Set FirstPeriod = @p1,
        SecondPeriod = @p2,
        ThirdPeriod = @p3,
        FourthPeriod =@p4,
        FirstSemesterExam = @firstExam,
        FirstSemesterAvg = @firstAvg,
        FifthPeriod = @p5,
        SixPeriod = @p6,
        SecondSemesterExam = @SecondExam,
        SecondSemesterAvg = @SecondAvg
    where 
        dbo.French.StudentId = @StuId
end



Exec gradesInsert 1, 90, 98, 77, 69, 70, 72, 99, 100
```

I want the student average to have two numbers to the left of the point and scale two places to the right of the decimal point like ex (99.43).

I don't know what I'm missing here guys, but I will appreciate you honest opinions and feedbacks.

Thanks Guys!!

Answer (score 5):

The definition of a `DECIMAL` column in SQL Server is defined as:

```
DECIMAL(precision, scale)
```

where `precision` stands for the **total** number of digits, and `scale` for the number of digits after the decimal point.

So `decimal(2,2)` means: a **total** of 2 digits, thereof 2 **after** the decimal point.

With this declaration, you can basically only store values from `.00` to `.99` in that column. Is that **really** what you want/need??

Read all the details about [decimal and numeric types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) in SQL Server on MSDN .....

Comment: Thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to work it out. It seems like to have a decimal digit of two places to the right and two or more places to the left; you have to set the decimal value with a precision of five(5) and a scale of two(2).
    Ex. myNmber decimal(5,2)

Remember the scale value is subtracted from the precision value. So, in the example above, a scale value of two(2) subtracted from a precision value of five(5) result to a value of three(3) which can hold any three(3) digits number on the left. This works for division wherein the dividend is a three digits number.

If you want to do a division wherein the dividend is a four(4) digits number then your field should look something like this. Ex. myNumber decimal(6,2).

So, in my case all I had to do was to redefined things in my table as follows:

```
 FirstSemesterAvg decimal(6,2),
 SecondSemesterAvg decimal(6,2),
```

And also in my procedure:

```
declare @firstAvg decimal(6,2) = cast(@add1 as decimal(6,2)) / 4
declare @SecondAvg decimal(6,2) = cast(@add2 as decimal(6,2)) / 4
```

It works fine guys.